# Are Cassandra JMX metric(Stages and Operations) cluster-wide or local?

Tags: cassandra

In Cassandra JMX metrics, 
below few categories show something weird pattern.

```
  "org.apache.cassandra.request:type=MutationStage", "CompletedTasks"
  "org.apache.cassandra.request:type=ReadRepairStage", "CompletedTasks"
  "org.apache.cassandra.request:type=ReadStage", "CompletedTasks"
  "org.apache.cassandra.request:type=ReplicateOnWriteStage", "CompletedTasks"
  "org.apache.cassandra.request:type=RequestResponseStage", "CompletedTasks"

  "org.apache.cassandra.db:type=StorageProxy", "ReadOperations"
  "org.apache.cassandra.db:type=StorageProxy", "WriteOperations"
```

I thought these metrics are not cluster-side (i.e. accumulated node locally, not total nodes' sum).
But, Referring the JMX Metrics graph(home-made monitoring), these metrics are summed of total node's activities.

[image: Cassandra Stage's CompletedTasks Chart]
The cluster monitored have 10 cassandra nodes.
And you can see that all node's completed stage counter have same value.

Does above jmx metric present all cassandra nodes' total activities ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

They are just for one node.  For a well balanced cluster they should be roughly similar.

Comment: Thanks, "For a well balanced cluster they should be roughly similar." ==> But they looks like showing the same metrics (Almost same metrics ^^).

Comment: "Roughly similar" and "almost the same" are synonyms. :)

Comment: jbellis. Thanks for your thoughtful explanation. ^^;